# Invalid Product Identifier for In-app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am trying test my app for in-app purchase feature. I created some products for In-app purchase from itunes connect. I created these products as non-consumable products. But when I try to purchase the in-app products from my app, the response is "Invalid Product Identifier". I have no clue what does this error means. Please note that I have not yet submitted the app for review. I want to do In-app purchase testing before submitting the app. Can anybody guide me in the right direction or resources. Thank you.

Comment: Please [search on the error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D%5Bin-app-purchase%5D+Invalid+Product+Identifier).

Comment: Thanks for the resource. I think my problem is that I am yet to submit the app to the store. I thought of submitting the app after testing the app for in-app purchase.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is resolved after signing agreement for paid application. Once the agreement is signed, I am able to test purchasing through my test user account in sandbox environment without any problem.

Comment: Than you, this was also my problem (I still needed to fill in the Tax Information). This answer still stands relevant in 2017.

Comment: Ahhhhh, hopefully this fixes the darn problem! But I still get this error on Android, so there is probably still something wrong. But hey, one step forward